# response produced exception – java client / WCF web service

Tags: java, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web service who calls from a java client. The java client uses a fixed WSDL file. That means that i have to manipulate my web service to run with the client. I have more than one method and some are working.
I get the exception in the client, if i send a list as response. The specification from the java client is:

```
<ns2:methodName xmlns:ns2="http://namespace.de">
 <return>
  <element1>2015-10-12T11:41:31+02:00</element1>
  <element2>testText</element2>
  <filename>documentName.pdf</filename>
  <element3>99999</element3>
 </return>
 <return>
  <element1>2015-10-12T11:49:13+02:00</element1>
  <element2>test 2txt</element2>
  <filename>test.txt</filename>
  <element3>99999</element3>
 <return>
</ns2: methodName >
```

XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="methodName">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="tns:dataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I have tried a lot of alternative, here is one of them.

IService:

```
<OperationContract(Action:="http://namespace/methodNameRequest", Name:="methodName", ReplyAction:="http://namespace/methodNameResponse")>    
        Function methodName(input As methodName) As methodNameResponse

<MessageContract()>
Public Class methodNameResponse
   <MessageBodyMember(Name:="return", [Namespace]:="")>
   Public result 
End class
```

No datatype, because there are more than one response value, that call return.

Service:

```
Public Function methodName(input As methodName) As methodNameResponse Implements IService.methodName

    Dim ListeDataType As New List(Of datatype)
    Dim value As methodNameResponse = New methodNameResponse()
    value.result = ListeDataType
    Return ListeDataType
End Function
```

soapMesssage:

```
<methodNameResponse xmlns="http://namespace.de">
 <return xsi:type="q1:ArrayOfdataType" xmlns="" xmlns:q1="http://namespace.de">
   <q1:dataType>
     <q1:element1>2014-03-14T21:00:40</q1: element1>
     <q1:element2> test text </q1: element2>
     <q1:filename >test.txt</q1:filename>
     <q1:element3>99999</q1: element3>
   </q1:dataType>
   <q1:dataType >
     <q1:element1>2014-03-14T21:00:40</q1: element1>
     <q1:element2> test2 text </q1: element2>
     <q1:filename >test2.txt</q1: filename>
     <q1:element3>99999</q1: element3>
   </q1:dataType >
 </return>
</methodNameResponse>
```

With this i get the exception: q1:ArrayofDataType cannot be resolved as a type definition for element "return". I have tried more than one, but i happy to tried it again, if i become a good Idea to solve this behavior. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete .wsdl. I presume you do have the full one and aren't trying to reverse a partial snippet? The svcutil command line utility should help you.
svcutil /language:VB /mc service.wsdl types.xsd
This will create the message contract types for you and hopefully provide a working interface. If it doesn't, then the web service you want to look like doesn't conform to correct specs and you start getting into advanced territory with custom dispatchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MattC Thank you for your hint. It helped me to solve my problem.

Solution:

Build the interface with

```
SvcUtil.exe /importXmlTypes *.wsdl *.xsd /language:VB
```

/importXmlTypes - this I have to use, because the standard call, get an exception , because of duplicate declaration ‘return’. After some corrections it works with this code:

**IService:**

```
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://namespace/methodNameRequest", ReplyAction:="http://namespace/methodNameResponse"),
     System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()>
    Function methodName(ByVal input As methodName) As <System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name:="return")> methodNameResponse

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0"),
 System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName:="methodName", WrapperNamespace:="http://namespace", IsWrapped:=True)>
Partial Public Class methodNameRequest
    <System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute([Namespace]:="http://namespace", Order:=0),
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>
    Public element1 As String
…
End class

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0"),
 System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName:="methodNameResponse", WrapperNamespace:="http://namespace", IsWrapped:=True)>
Partial Public Class methodNameResponse

    <System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute([Namespace]:="http://namespace", Order:=0),
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>
    Public [return]() As dataType

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal [return]() As dataType)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.[return] = [return]
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Service:**

```
Public Function methodName(input As methodName) As methodNameResponse Implements IService.methodName
…
            Dim ListResponse As New methodNameResponse()
            ListResponse.return = ListeDataType.ToArray
            Return ListResponse 
End Function
```